# Accessing AppConfig settings via Injection

Tags: c#

I have values in my AppConfig like this...

```
<appSettings>
<add key="id" value="1234" />
</appSettings>
```

In the IAppConfig class I have...

```
 public interface IAppConfig
 {
    string id{ get; }
 }
   
   [ConfigurationProperty("id")]
    public string id
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this["id"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["id"] = value;
        }
    }
```

In a startup class I have

```
using SimpleInjector;

   public static Container Container;

    public static void Start()
    {
        Container = new Container();

         IAppConfig appConfig = (IAppConfig)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("appSettings");
         Container.Register<IAppConfig, AppConfig>(Lifestyle.Singleton);

    }
```

And I inject it into another class...

```
       private readonly IAppConfig config;

    public ClassName(IAppConfig config)
    {
        this.config = config;
        
    }
```

However the id (and other values) come up as empty strings. This happens in the Getter.   I am calling the Start method before trying to access them.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created an appconfig object but have not registered that for injection.

Try the below:

Simplify you AppConfig class

```
 public class AppConfig
 {
    public string id{ get; set; }
 }

 var appconfig = new AppConfig{ id = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["id"] };
 
container.Register<AppConfig>(() => appconfig, Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

You can keep the Interface pattern as well

Comment: I get this...

System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Configuration.KeyValueInternalCollection' to type 'ProjectName.Config.IAppConfig'.'

Comment: There is an issue with this casting
(IAppConfig)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("appSettings");

Comment: Are you asking?  I assume there is an issue.  How would I inject the class?

Comment: I have updated my solution. Can you try? If it still doesn't work i will have to create a fiddlr.

Comment: GetSection is a method which is not valid in the current context.  Also where do you get the key variable?  Is that local?

Comment: It will just be ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["id"]  // "id" is the key in you app.config

Comment: Since I am no longer using the IAppConfig interface, how would I inject that id value into other classes?

Comment: Oh wait it's supposed to be Container.Register<IAppConfig>

Comment: in constructor inject AppConfig. You can also use IAppConfig if u want, just write some more code. The following code works, here i have registered dependency and then resolving it with type "AppConfig"  ///// container.Register<AppConfig>(() => appconfig, Lifestyle.Singleton);
   AppConfig data = container.GetInstance<AppConfig>(); //////

Comment: That was some work, I was making a fiddle. Well happy to help. Enjoy Coding

Answer (score 1):

You register type `AppConfig` as singleton implementation of type `IAppConfig`, so when you request `IAppConfig` from container, you'll get an instance created by container, and not 'appConfig' you created in `Start`.
You need to register instance like:

```cs
Container.Instance<IAppConfig>(appConfig);
```

Comment: Container does not have an Instance property.  Do you mean RegisterInstance?

Comment: Probably, I haven't checked the exact syntax of that container, but most of containers have some method to register instance of object as some interface.